# How can I iterate through all rows of a dataframe to apply a look up function to a string value and apply the result to a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a dataframe with several columns of personal data for each row (person). I want to apply a function to look up each person's city or state in regional lists, and then apply the result to a new column "Region" in the same dataframe.

I have been able to make the same operation work with a very simplified dataframe with categories for colors and vehicles (see below). But when I try to do it with the personal data, it won't work the same way and I don't understand why.

I've read through many theads on lambda functions, but I think what I'm asking is too complex for that. Most solutions deal with numerical data and I'm using strings, but as I said, I was able to make it work with one dataset. Obviously I'm new here. I'd also appreciate advice on how to build the new column as part of the function instead of having to build it as a separate step, but that isn't frustrating me as much as the main question.

#### This example works:

```
# Python: import pandas
import pandas as pd
# Simple dataframe. Empty column 'type'.
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'], 
                  'two':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'], 
                  'three': ['car','bus','red','blue','truck','pencil','yellow','green'],
                  'type':''})
```

df displays:

```
    one two three   type
0   1   A   car     
1   2   B   bus     
2   3   C   red     
3   4   D   blue    
4   5   E   truck   
5   6   F   pencil  
6   7   G   yellow  
7   8   H   green
```

Now define lists and custom function:

```
# Definte lists of colors and vehicles
colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow']
vehicles = ['car','truck','bus','motorcycle']

# Create function 'celltype' to return values based on x
def celltype (x):
    if x in colors: return 'color' 
    elif x in vehicles: return 'vehicle'
    else: return 'other'
```

Then construct a loop to iterate through each row and apply the function:

```
# Write loop to iterate through df rows and apply function 'celltype' to column 'three' in each row
for index, row in df.iterrows(): 
    row['type'] = celltype(row['three'])
```

And in this case the result is just what I want:

```
    one two three   type
0   1   A   car     vehicle
1   2   B   bus     vehicle
2   3   C   red     color
3   4   D   blue    color
4   5   E   truck   vehicle
5   6   F   pencil  other
6   7   G   yellow  color
7   8   H   green   color
```

---

#### This example doesn't work, and I don't know why:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Last Name':['SMITH','JONES','WILSON','DOYLE','ANDERSON'], 'First Name':['TOM','DICK','HARRY','MICHAEL','KEVIN'],
                    'Code':[12,34,56,78,90], 'Deparment':['Research','Management','Maintenance','Marketing','IT'],
                    'City':['NEW YORK','BOSTON','SAN FRANCISCO','DALLAS','DETROIT'], 'State':['NY','MA','CA','TX','MI'], 'Region':''})
```

df1 displays:

```
    Last Name   First Name  Code    Deparment   City        State   Region
0   SMITH       TOM         12  Research        NEW YORK    NY  
1   JONES       DICK        34  Management      BOSTON      MA  
2   WILSON      HARRY       56  Maintenance     SAN FRANCISCO   CA  
3   DOYLE       MICHAEL     78  Marketing       DALLAS      TX  
4   ANDERSON    KEVIN       90  IT              DETROIT     MI
```

Again, defining lists and functions:

```
# Define lists for regions
east = ['NEW YORK','BOSTON']
west = ['SAN FRANCISCO','LOS ANGELES']
south = ['TX']

# Create function 'region' to return values based on x
def region (x):
    if x in east: return 'east' 
    elif x in west: return 'west'
    elif x in south: return 'south'
    else: return 'other'

# Write loop to iterate through df1 rows and apply function 'region' to column 'City' in each row
for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
    row['Region'] = region(row['City'])
    if row['Region'] == 'other': row['Region'] = region(row['State'])
```

This results in an unchanged df1. The 'Region' column is still blank. We should see "east", "east", "west", "south", "other". The only difference in the code is the additional 'if' statement, to catch Dallas by state (which is something I need for my real world dataset). But I think that line is sound and I get the same result without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, `apply` and `iterrows` are slow, so try not to use them, ever.

What I usually do in this situation is to create a pair of `forward` and `backward` dicts:

```
forward = {'east': east,
           'west': west,
           'south': south}

backward = {x:k for k,v in forward.items() for x in v}
```

And then update with `map`. Since you want to update based on two columns, `fillna` will be helpful:

```
df1['Region'] = (df1['State'].map(backward)
                    .fillna(df1['City'].map(backward))
                    .fillna('other')
                )
```

gives:

```
  Last Name First Name  Code    Deparment           City State Region
0     SMITH        TOM    12     Research       NEW YORK    NY   east
1     JONES       DICK    34   Management         BOSTON    MA   east
2    WILSON      HARRY    56  Maintenance  SAN FRANCISCO    CA   west
3     DOYLE    MICHAEL    78    Marketing         DALLAS    TX  south
4  ANDERSON      KEVIN    90           IT        DETROIT    MI  other
```

Comment: Thank you! This totally worked, and to your point, it is faster, even with real world data. The backward dict is a new trick to me. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with using `iterrows`. You should, in general, never modify something you are iterating over. In this case, the `iterrows` is creating a copy of your data and so is not actually modifying your `df1`. The copy is something that might or might not happen depending on the circumstances, so something like this is something you generally want to avoid doing.

You can make sure it modifies the original by calling the Dataframe directly with `at`:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows(): 
    df1.at[index, 'Region'] = region(row['City'])
    if df1.at[index, 'Region'] == 'other': df1.at[index, 'Region'] = region(row['State'])
```

Comment: That's a good tip. It confused me that the iterrows code worked with one dataset and not with the other, but I guess it's not predictable. While I was working with it, I got the df1 dataset to work by removing the 'Code' column. Something about it may have stumbled on the numeric data perhaps? But either way, the selected answer is probably a better approach than using iterrows in the first place. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @WilliamCollins No problem. changing something could cause it to work but because of the unpredictable nature of the way you were doing it, you still do not want to do that as it might not always work. My answer was trying to explain to you the why your code didn't work. The other solution is definitely faster however and probably better.